# wordpress custom field to select from existing posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm building a WP site and at one specific page i want to have a custom field in wich the user can select from existing content to be linked there. (english is not my native lang :)

In my case: 
I have a services page where the admin can add new services. 
I have a doctors page where the admin can add new doctors.

I want to have the option to link one doctor to one specific service.

Can this be done?

Comment: I've found a nice plugin in wich this task can be done.

It's name is: Advanced Custom Fields (my version: 3.5.2)

When you add a new field you can set the filed's type to relationship... and that's it! :)

Hope this helps to some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other said, [Advanced Custom Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) is the answer to your and most needs regarding the data hierarchy management in wordpress.

In addiction I suggest to you to read [this good tutorial](http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-post-type-relationships/) about the use of [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/), another good plugin that does the same work of *ACF*.

Considere moreover that both plugins ask money if you want more functionalities.

Comment: How would you so this without a plugin?

Comment: You can install [Meta Box plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) (you can also embed it into your theme!) and the [register the meta boxes easly](http://metabox.io/docs/registering-meta-boxes/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plugin url : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ that makes relationship between custom filed. It will you.

Comment: How would you so this without a plugin?